# View not front on

Tags: 3d-view, interface

When I'm in side view, I now see the sides of the object instead of it being flat like it was before. I've downloaded the most recent version of Blender, and now it's stuck like this, and I can't change it back.

Thanks

[image: issue demo]

Comment: Hi :). Perhaps you're looking for *View > Orthographic*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your side view is in perspective instead of orthographic. You can manually switch between perspective and orthographic by pressing <kbd>numpad 5</kbd>.
By default, Blender automatically switches between perspective/orthographic view when you switch between free view and side/top/front views.

This is enabled by the "auto perspective" option in the preferences:

[image: auto perspective location]